# How to Call Second, third, or whatever Element From a set in a List in Dart or Flutter

Tags: flutter, list, element

As an example, if you have a list containing several sets of data as the following example of list

Set mySet = Set.from([{7,8,9}, {1,2,3}, {15,25,50,75,66}]);

How to call any specific element in such situation ? How to get the 2nd element of the secound set of data ?

Comment: a Set generically has no ordering so asking for "second element" has no definition. What precisely are you asking?

Answer (score -1):

I found the method like this

```
  print('${mySet.elementAt(1)}');
  print('${mySet.elementAt(0).elementAt(1)}');
  print('elment is : ${mySet.elementAt(1).elementAt(2)}');
  print('elment is : ${mySet.elementAt(2).elementAt(4)}'); 

  
  
  mySet.forEach((value) => {print(value)});
```

The output :

```
{1, 2, 3}
8
elment is : 3
elment is : 66
{7, 8, 9}
{1, 2, 3}
{15, 25, 50, 75, 66}
```